# Can't resolve all the promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a filter function. I have categories and cities, that come like this: `['New York'], ['Cars']`, and I'm iterating them
to find the products of that category or city. The idea is to put on the `products` variable the products that come from each city, or category, and then return them to the user.

I fail to return them because when I console log `products` in the async function it's displaying the products, but although I push thos in the `promises` array, that array is empty when I call `Promise.all`.

I know that I need the promises to resolve so I expect to collect them in `promises` and to await their resolution with `Promise.all` at the end and convert the data and return all products collected, but the `promises` array is empty.

```
import { Product } from "../../models";
import { Response } from "../../utils";

export default async function ProductsFilters(req, res) {
  try {
    const { Cities, Categories } = req.body;

    let products = [];
    let promises = [];

    if (Cities.length > 0) {
      Cities.map(async (city) => {
        const results = await Product.find({ City: city });
        return promises.push(results);
      });
    }

    if (Categories.length > 0) {
      Categories.map(async (category) => {
        const results = await Product.find({ Category: category });
        return promises.push(results);
      });
    }

    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    results.map((result) => products.push(result));

    if (products.length > 0) Response( res, 200, true, "Të gjitha produktet u morën me sukses.", products);
    else Response(res, 404, false, "Asnjë produkt nuk u gjet në platformë.", null);
  } catch (error) {
    Response( res, 500, false, "Gabim i brendshëm i serverit gjatë gjetjes së produkteve.", null);
  }
}
```

I'm using Mongo Database and Mongoose to fetch the products, so `.find` function is returning the products that it matches.

Comment: *"but is not working"*: please edit your question and explain what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: @trincot I have tried to update it more, can you understand?

Comment: I made edits to your question, as "is not working" is not a good problem statement. I suppose you mean that the `promises` array is empty at a time you expected it to not be empty. Please reread your question to check that this correctly reflects what you mean and ask.

Comment: As a general rule, there is no need to use an `if (array.length > 0)` guard around a call to `array.forEach(...)` or `array.map(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The the `map` method is synchronous even when you pass it a callback that is asynchronous:

```
      Cities.map(async (city) => {
        const results = await Product.find({ City: city });
        return promises.push(results);
      });
```

Those callbacks will return as soon as they encounter `await`, so the `promises` array will still be empty when the `.map()` call returns.

Also `map` *returns* an array, which you ignore. Instead you call `push` inside the `map` callback. That is bad practice. If you don't expect a returned array, then don't use `map`, but `forEach` or `for`. If you do want to populate an array, then take benefit from the array returned by `map`.

Here is a rewrite:

```
async function ProductsFilters(req, res) {
    try {
        const { Cities, Categories } = req.body;
        const products = await Promise.all([
            ...Cities.map(async (City) => Product.find({ City })),
            ...Categories.map(async (Category) => Product.find({ Category }))
        ]);
        if (products.length > 0) {
            Response(res, 200, true, "Të gjitha produktet u morën me sukses.", products);
        } else {
            Response(res, 404, false, "Asnjë produkt nuk u gjet në platformë.", null);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Response(res, 500, false, "Gabim i brendshëm i serverit gjatë gjetjes së produkteve.", null);
    }
}
```